# How to delay the loading of html body from head section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my `html` file's head section, I've added a library `testLibrary.js` and in that `js` file, I'm asking for a response from server side. Is there a way to load the body after I get the response?

This is my `html` head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover">

    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://*****.com/js/testLibrary.js"></script>

</head>
```

Inside the `testLibrary.js` I'm doing this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get(host+ "/ws/getInfo?pid=" + id, function (data, status) {
            try {
                if (data[0].status == "VALID") {
                    //let the body load
                } else {
                   // redirect to somewhere else
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

I want the body to stop loading before I get `response` and verify. Is it possible to do? Or is there a way around? The library can be used by anyone so I won't have the control of body.

Comment: I think you can do a loading animation in your body, until you get response from testLibrary.js, then remove animation and load you real body data.

Comment: @KevinZhang i can't do that cause if you see the last section of my question, the js file can be used by anyone and I won't have the control over their body. So I've to do it inside the js file

Comment: @Araf i have a question? why you'r using jquery with angular ?

Comment: @JazibBashir Ignore the angular part. I'm removing this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a pre-loader to full screen with overlay before server-side call is started and while the call is being processed, on success replace your content and remove the overlay loader.

```
$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
     ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

Add the HTML element at the bottom:

```
<div class="modal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
   Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
   with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
   for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
   our animation centered, and no-repeating */
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading .modal {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```